# Type Type mismatch: cannot convert from RegisterFragment to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here is my Code and The problem occurs in Switch Case....plz help

package com.example.atg.adapter;

```
import com.example.atg.LoginFragment;
import com.example.atg.RegisterFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            //Fragement for Android Tab
            return new LoginFragment();
        case 1:
           //Fragment for Ios Tab
            return new RegisterFragment();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2; //No of Tabs
    }


    }
```

RegisterFragment class

```
   package com.example.atg;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.net.NetworkInfo;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.example.atg.library.DatabaseHandler;
    import com.example.atg.library.UserFunctions;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
```

public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment {

```
    /**
     *  JSON Response node names.
     **/


    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";

    /**
     * Defining layout items.
     **/

    EditText inputFirstName;
    EditText inputLastName;
    EditText inputUsername;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    Button btnRegister;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.register);

    /**
     * Defining all layout items
     **/
        inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById1(R.id.fname);
        inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById1(R.id.lname);
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById1(R.id.uname);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById1(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById1(R.id.pword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);



/**
 * Button which Switches back to the login screen on clicked
 **/

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bktologin);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }



        });

        /**
         * Register Button click event.
         * A Toast is set to alert when the fields are empty.
         * Another toast is set to alert Username must be 5 characters.
         **/

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (  ( !inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputFirstName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputLastName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    if ( inputUsername.getText().toString().length() > 4 ){
                    NetAsync(view);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Username should be minimum 5 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "One or more fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
       }
    protected Context getApplicationContext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    private EditText findViewById1(int fname) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private Button findViewById(int register){
        return null;
    }
    private void setContentView(int register) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    /**
     * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working
     **/

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();

            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){


/**
 * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
 **/
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessRegister().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                registerErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }





    private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

/**
 * Defining Process dialog
 **/
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        String email,password,fname,lname,uname;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById1(R.id.uname);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById1(R.id.pword);
               fname = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
               lname = inputLastName.getText().toString();
                email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                uname= inputUsername.getText().toString();
                password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {


        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname, password);

            return json;


        }
       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
       /**
        * Checks for success message.
        **/
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                        String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

                            registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");


                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            /**
                             * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
                             **/

                            UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                            logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                            /**
                             * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                             * Launch Registered screen
                             **/

                            Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registered.class);

                            /**
                             * Close all views before launching Registered screen
                            **/
                            registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            startActivity(registered);


                              finish();
                        }

                        else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                        }
                        else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                        }

                    }


                        else{
                        pDialog.dismiss();

                            registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                        }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();


                }
            }}
        public void NetAsync(View view){
            new NetCheck().execute();
        }
        public void finish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        public ConnectivityManager getSystemService(String connectivityService) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

}
```

Errors:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

```
            Type mismatch: cannot convert from LoginFragment to Fragment    TabsPagerAdapter.java   /ATG/src/com/example/atg/adapter    line 20 Java Problem
            Type mismatch: cannot convert from RegisterFragment to Fragment TabsPagerAdapter.java   /ATG/src/com/example/atg/adapter    line 23 Java Problem
```

Comment: is your RegisterFragment extending Fragment?

Comment: might help if you post the RegisterFragment class too

Comment: yes my RegisterFragment class extending fragment

Comment: Try typecasting your Login/Register fragments before returning them.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The problem is that your RegisterFragment is a `android.app.Fragment`, but you are returning a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in your `getItem(...)` method. Check your import statements in both classes where you are importing `Fragment` and make sure they are either both importing the normal `android.app.Fragment` or the support library `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` depending on your application's needs.

Comment: +1 for epic awesomeness.  HOURS of my life saved from reading this.

Comment: perfect one.really helped. Thanks alot.

Comment: wasted 1 hour restarting my Android Studio and system... ha ha ha

Answer (score 8):

the problem is you are importing

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

inside `RegisterFragment` and

Importing

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

inside adapter.

If you are using Support v4 import `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` in RegisterFragment as well.