# Error when trying to create swipe view With tab bar

Tags: java, android

I'm new to andoid and now trying to create swipe view With tab bar in android.

**TabPagerAdapter**

```
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

           public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
                    public TabPagerAdapter(Fragment

    Manager fm) {
                    super(fm);

                @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int i) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:

                        return new Information();
                    case 1:

                        return new WorkForce();
                    case 2:

                        return new WorkDetailsTable();
                }


         return null;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-

        generated method stub
                return 3; //No of Tabs you can give your number of tabs
            }


        }
```

**Information.java**

```
     import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
            import android.app.Dialog;
            import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;
            import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
            import android.widget.DatePicker;
            import android.widget.EditText;
            import android.widget.Spinner;
            import com.example.project.project.database.MyDatabaseHelper;
            import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.Calendar;
            import java.util.List;
              public class Information extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
                    private Spinner spinner, spinner2, spinner3;

                    private MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
                    private com.example.project.project.API.InfoAPI ts;
                    private static EditText txtDate;
                    private DateDialog dialog;
                    private static String a;
                    private static String b;
                    private static String c;
                    private static String date1;

                    @Override
                    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        View info = inflater.inflate(R.layout.information, container, false);
                        dialog = new DateDialog();
                        txtDate = (EditText) info.findViewById(R.id.editText5);
                        txtDate.setOnClickListener(this);

                        addItemsOnSpinner();
                        addItemsOnSpinner2();
                        return info;

        }


                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");

                    }


                    public void addItemsOnSpinner() {
                        spinner = (Spinner) info.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        list.add("1");
                        list.add("2");
                        list.add("3");

                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Information.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


                    }

                    public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {
                        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        list.add("Sunny");
                        list.add("Cloudy");

                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Information.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);


                    }



                    public static class DateDialog extends android.app.DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
                        //  EditText txtdate;
                        Tab t;


                        public DateDialog() {

                        }


                        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
                        }

                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                            String date = day + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + year;
                            txtDate.

setText(date);
                        date1 = txtDate.getText().toString();
                        return;

                    }
                }


            }
```

**Error**

```
   Information cannot converted to fragment
```

I refer to [Type Type mismatch: cannot convert from RegisterFragment to Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003463/type-type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-registerfragment-to-fragment) but it doesn't help.

**Edited**

```
 `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;` has imported to both classes but it written as unused import statement
```

In Information.java, onClick() has changed to

```
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");

    }
```

Comment: What's wrong here? :)

Comment: in your onClick method remove the prefix -> `android.app.` and just keep `FragmentTransaction ft`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using v4 for Fragments and not for FragmentTransaction:

```
 import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Make sure to consistently use v4 or just app.

for v4 : getSupportFragmentManager()
for non-v4 : getFragmentManager()

Comment: I have import android.app.FragmentTransaction; to both classes, but it not works

Comment: it should not work because everything else is v4. Change to android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction and getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`